# Change breadcrumbs homepage text

Tags: wordpress

I've been trying to work on this little thingy for almost a full day so any help would be highly appreciated

You can see how the breadcrumbs looks like in here:
https://www.bitcoinhoy.co/criptomonedas/ethereum/

I managed to find the relevant php file and here's the code:

```
enter code here
<!-- ** Breadcrumb ** -->
<?php
    if( !empty( $global_breadcrumb ) ) {

        if(empty($settings)) { $settings['enable-sub-title'] = true; }

        if( isset( $settings['enable-sub-title'] ) && $settings['enable-sub-title'] ) {

            $breadcrumbs = array();
            $bstyle = digibit_cs_get_option( 'breadcrumb-style', 'default' );
            $separator = '<span class="'.digibit_cs_get_option( 'breadcrumb-delimiter', 'fa default' ).'"></span>';

            if( is_singular('post') ){
                $cat = get_the_category();
                $cat = $cat[0];
                $breadcrumbs[] = get_category_parents( $cat, true, $separator );
            }

            $breadcrumbs[] = the_title( '<span class="current">', '</span>', false );
            $bcsettings = isset( $settings['breadcrumb_background'] ) ? $settings['breadcrumb_background'] : array();
            $style = digibit_breadcrumb_css( $bcsettings );

            digibit_breadcrumb_output ( the_title( '<h1>', '</h1>',false ), $breadcrumbs, $bstyle, $style );
        }
    }
?><!-- ** Breadcrumb End ** -->
```

Any  idea how can I modify the "home" text to something else?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Digibit is a premium theme. Modifying a theme file may not be a great idea because if they update the theme, it will break the modifications you make.

What you can do is add this in your CSS (perhaps in Customize > Additional CSS):

```
.breadcrumb a:first-child {
  font-size: 0;
}

.breadcrumb a:first-child:after {
  content: "Something Else";
  font-size: 14px;
}
```